# how to remove error which is related formbuilder with jquery-ui-sortable in react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

please help me i beginner in this filde i just wanted to add the plugine but they show the error which is attached in the 3rd image link . i already install every plugine like formbuilder , jquery , hquery-ui-sortable . but i am broswer they show an error . how could be i slove it
[[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4v2I.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4v2I.png)
[image: Package .js file]
[image: Broswer error]

Comment: Why you need to use jquery in react? could you please specify the need? that mean what you gonna accomplish?

Comment: okay i remove it ,, but they given the error

Comment: In `package.json`, the `"type"` define is `"module"`, try to use `import` instead of `require()`.

Comment: just like "import "jquery-ui-sortable" this way

Comment: if i import it they given the error of jQuery ,, which is i already install